# What is the difference between ReleaseFloatArrayElements and DeleteLocalRef

Tags: c++, memory-management, android-ndk

I'm trying to do an android apps using JNI. I have a method that take as input an array(`jfloatArray` featurePoints):

```
jfloat* flt1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements(featurePoints,0);
```

After using this array i tried to release the memory. Should I use

```
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(featurePoints, flt1, 0);
```

or

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(featurePoints);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call ReleaseXxArrayElement() when you have used GetXxArrayElements() to undo the work.

```
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements( featurePoints , (jfloat *)flt1, 0);
// we cleanup local ref 
env->DeleteLocalRef(featurePoints);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that GetArrayElements doesn't return an Object, so there's no local reference to release.  It may be useful to delete the local ref for the array object as well, but that's an independent decision.  See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html .